# Use powershell to excecute SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and  need help.
I have a single job in SQL Agent Job and the job name 'RunMeFirst'
I can run this job in SQL server but I want to run in PowerShell command.
Can someone hep and show me step by step what do I need to setup so I can use PowerShell command to run this job.
Thank for your help.

Comment: this shows one way >>> [SOLVED] Start a SQL Agent Job with Powershell - Spiceworks — https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1752564-start-a-sql-agent-job-with-powershell <<< ///// it also recommends using powershell to trigger stored procedure to run the SQL agent job.

Comment: This is too complicate and I don't know how to begin with? I really need step by step. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately, i am not skilled with SQL _at all_. [*blush*] hopefully, some kind person with more skill on this will help ...

Comment: OK, Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are most welcome ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to run the job is with the `sp_start_job` msdb procedure. This can be invoked from PowerShell using .NET SqlClient objects like this example:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$command =  New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.sp_start_job", $connection)
$command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
($command.Parameters.Add("@job_name", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 128)).Value = "RunMeFirst"
$connection.Open()
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: After change correct server name connection ( above) . Run Powershell with admin. Paste these lines above in Powershell command and nothing happen. Do I miss something?

Comment: I just learned how to install powershell module. I will continue to research until I can run these lines.

Comment: @ngoc, modern version of Windows include PowerShell without a separate install. Search for "Windows PowerShell ISE" (also under the Windows PowerShell program group) and launch the tool. Click View--Script pane and paste the code into the editor window. Press F5 to run the script.